# Should we have MathJax support?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, formatting

As of now, I haven't seen any questions that neccesarily need MathJax formatting, but I'm sure that at some point it'll be needed.

Should we have MathJax support?

Comment: **Yes.** Computer graphics has boat-loads of linear algebra. We're going to run into answers (and probably some questions) with the need to show equations.

Comment: Yes. It would be great we need to be able to describe math easily.

Comment: Yes... it's definitely necessary...

Comment: As more people become interested in physically-based rendering (it's well-established in non-realtime imaging, but happening in the real-time field now), it's only going to become more important. Pick any SIGGRAPH paper and count the equations. Yes, even this one: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ph/jello/jello.html

Comment: Why it is not active yet?

Comment: Just realised on math.SE they can [even use MathJax in comments!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418729/how-to-find-out-which-number-is-larger-without-a-calculator#comment2891834_1418992)

Comment: @Drazick because the community has given most upvotes to the answer that says we should wait. I [don't feel there is any reason to wait](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/77/231). If anyone wants to change their vote based on this, they can leave a comment requesting the answer be edited to allow them to.

Comment: Remember that on Meta you can indicate your opinion by both upvoting and downvoting.

Comment: @trichoplax, The answer which received most votes says it should be implemented and just mentions a bug. Is the bug eve relevant here? We have no issues with MathJax in DSP.SE.

Comment: @trichoplax, More over, if you sum the amount of votes for both answers which are pro, you'll see they exceed. On top of that, I'm willing to bet most people up voted the answer saw the meaning, yes, we want it.

Comment: @Drazick it has been established that the [bug is no reason to delay](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/77/231) now.

Comment: @Drazick I'd like to see MathJax as soon as possible, but summing the votes doesn't really work as people can upvote both.

Comment: @Drazick I don't think there's anyone against having MathJax here (including Martin - see my linked meta post). It's just a little unclear what people are voting for. Once we have mods they can raise this with Stack Exchange staff and the current votes may turn out to be sufficient. Certainly the arguments seem sufficient.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Edited to clarify my opinion, feel free to change your vote.**

Computer graphics can be very maths-heavy so I think MathJax would be a great addition to this site. **I think we should definitely get MathJax**, but the community should be aware of the following side effects of activating it:

We've had MathJax for a short while on CodeGolf.SE, and [there is at least one bug](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5043/8478) that may affect Stack Snippets if we get them as well. This is probably not a big deal on this site, but should be kept in mind. The other minor drawback is that posts containing MathJax look pretty messy in the search results, but all the other sites using MathJax seem to be getting along with that as well.

Comment: I'd still say yes. If there are problems with MathJax, then they're problems faced elsewhere on SE. When they're fixed elsewhere, they'll be fixed here, and we'll already have good answers with MathJax stuff in them.

Comment: @Qix SO does not have mathjax because its heavy

Comment: @joojaa never said SO had mathjax.

Comment: @joojaa not quite sure I understand. Mathjax is heavy for questions that use it, but the benefits outweigh the costs in those cases.

Comment: @joojaa I don't think so. YouTube does not have the same problems as MathJax, because the embedding happens server side. MathJax's drawbacks result from having to deliver the MathJax JavaScript with every single page request.

Comment: @Qix but its heavy on stackexhange to host!

Comment: You guys might want to continue this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26589/computer-graphics).

Comment: @joojaa MathJax is on other stacks, I don't see how that's a problem...

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I don't understand, what's your opinion, have it or not? The implementation is the same in every SE Community. It works great on DSP, Stats, Math, etc... Why would we have problems here?

Comment: @Drazick Sorry I forgot to reply to your comment. My opinion is we *should* have it. I just wanted to raise the possible issues so people are aware of them and we don't repeat the experience we had on code golf where everyone was suddenly like "ugh, no, if MathJax comes with these issues, we'd rather not have it". I don't think these problems will be a big deal here, because code blocks and Stack Snippets are used differently here than they are on code golf. (The sites you mentioned haven't encountered these issues because I assume they don't have Stack Snippets activated.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner, As I understand it now, your answer is used to have a reason not to implement it now and delay the integration. If I understand correctly, it is not what you meant. Hence you should make it clear in your answer.

Comment: @Drazick good point, done.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, definitely. While there might not yet be a question that really needs it, once the first matrix and vector computations come in -- and they *will* definitely come and seem well-fit here (as they did in the previous iteration of that site) -- we'll definitely need it for that stuff to looks reasonably good and not be a pain to write (e.g. by misusing code blocks).

And that's not even everything there is to it. There's other geometric computations, complex rendering integrals, you name it. So **yeah, we definitely should have MathJax, and we should have it *NAOH*!**

Comment: I agree, I too believe we should see very soon questions and answers with "complex rendering integrals" (questions about physically based rendering for example)

Answer (score 11):

To back the general requests for MathJax support, the following is a community-editable list for anyone to add examples of questions which along with their answers would benefit from it:

- <s>[Is gamma still important to take into account?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/68/6)</s>
- <s>[How can I concentrate points in areas of higher curvature?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/57/6)</s>
- [What is fwidth and how does it work?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/61/6)
- [How is Gaussian Blur Implemented?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/39/6)
- [What is the "dipole approximation" for subsurface scattering?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/81/6)
- <s>[Brightness and contrast VS Gamma, is it possible to identify the gamma "correction amount"?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/83/6)</s>
- <s>[How to do a color separation with more than 3 primary colors](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/117/6)</s>
- <s>[How to implement a trackball in OpenGL?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/151/6)</s>
- <s>[How are volumetric effects handled in raytracing?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/227/6)</s>
- <s>[Why is it twice as expensive to make a noise function that can be tiled?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/250/why-is-it-twice-as-expensive-to-make-a-noise-function-that-can-be-tiled)</s>
- <s>[Is doing multiple Gaussian blurs the same as doing one larger blur?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/256/16)</s>
- <s>[Is all grid based noise inevitably anisotropic?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-all-grid-based-noise-inevitably-anisotropic--)</s>
- <s>[How does a 2D Fourier Transform of an image work?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/287/48)</s>
- <s>[Image rotation using FFT](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/336/48)</s>
- [Splitting of NURBS curves](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/340/splitting-of-nurbs-curves)
- <s>[Is all grid based noise inevitably anisotropic?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-all-grid-based-noise-inevitably-anisotropic)</s>
- <s>[Why integrate over a hemisphere (and not a sphere) to solve the rendering equation?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/312/why-integrate-over-a-hemisphere-and-not-a-sphere-to-solve-the-rendering-equati)</s>
- <s>[How to raytrace Bezier surfaces?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-to-raytrace-bezier-surfaces)</s>
- <s>[What are Affine Transformations?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/391/16)</s>
- <s>[Is this smaller grid for Poisson disc sampling still correct?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/324/is-this-smaller-grid-for-poisson-disc-sampling-still-correct)</s>
- <s>[Problem with definition of BSDF and radiance](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/1470/6)</s>
- <s>[Two-dimensional bounded area defined parametrically](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/two-dimensional-bounded-area-defined-parametrically)</s>
- <s>[Why is the transposed inverse of the model view matrix used to transform the normal vectors?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/why-is-the-transposed-inverse-of-the-model-view-matrix-used-to-transform-the-nor)</s>
- <s>[Does a sphere projected into 2D space always result in an ellipse?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/does-a-sphere-projected-into-2d-space-always-result-in-an-ellipse)</s>
- <s>[Why are Homogeneous Coordinates used in Computer Graphics?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/why-are-homogeneous-coordinates-used-in-computer-graphics)</s>
- <s>[Actual vs Perceived Brightness of RGB Colour](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/actual-vs-perceived-brightness-of-rgb-colour)</s>
- <s>[How to combine rotation in 2 axis into one matrix](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/how-to-combine-rotation-in-2-axis-into-one-matrix)</s>
- <s>[Transform a point into another point](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/transform-a-point-into-another-point)</s>
- <s>[Parametric line intersection test](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/parametric-line-intersection-test)</s>
- <s>[Energy Conservation for Blinn-Phong BRDF](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/energy-conservation-for-blinn-phong-brdf)</s>